# AngularJS - IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI - 'AuthenticationProperties' is an ambiguous reference

Tags: angularjs, redirect, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm implementing an AngularJS app that will use IdentityServer4 for Authorization.

I have a stand alone Angular app within a .Net Core 2.0 app that calls the api controller in the .net core app. if I browse to `http://localhost:5050/.well-known/openid-configuration` I am getting the json returned.

I have used [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient) example as a basis for my auth service:

```
function authService() {

    var config = {
        authority: "http://localhost:5050",
        client_id: "js",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5050/LocalizationAdmin/callback.html",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile api1",
        post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5050/LocalizationAdmin/index.html"
    };
    var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

    mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            log("User logged in", user.profile);
        } else {
            log("User not logged in");
        }
    });

    var service = {
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
    };
    return service;

    function login() {
        mgr.signinRedirect();
    }
```

In `callback.html` I have added:

```
<body>
    <script src="scripts/oidc-client.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Oidc.UserManager().signinRedirectCallback().then(function () {
            window.location = "index.html";
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

It is trying to redirect to:

```
http://localhost:5050/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Djs%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5050%252FLocalizationAdmin%252Fcallback.html%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520api1%26state%3Dd526351a26f74202badb7685022a6549%26nonce%3D6c858921378645ca8fcad973eb26cc72
```

However I just want it to redirect to the IdentityServer4 login screen. How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have added the UI templates from here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI

But I am getting a number of errors, could this be because I am using .Net Core 2.0 version: `assemblyref://IdentityServer4 (2.0.0-rc1-update1)`

`Error CS0104 'AuthenticationProperties' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties'`

Demo Project showing issue added to github [here](https://github.com/PaoloBrlo/SODemo1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how stable this is but I just used the powershell command pointing to the dev branch and it seems to be working.

`iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/dev/get.ps1'))`

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look instead at the quickstarts relating to 2.0.0-rc1-update1 which can be found here on the dev branch:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/dev/docs/quickstarts
as they have been also updated.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing in there about adding the UI?